# spring aop - exception while creating advice around JdbcTemplate methods

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I've a web application that uses apache dbcp and spring jdbc to perform database operations on an oracle database. I need to write a performance logger that logs the individual times of each database operation. I tried writing an around advice on all 'execute' methods of org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate but it results in an error when spring gets initialized. The logger class and the exception stacktrace is as follows:-

I also tried to use CGLIB proxies by enabling  but it errors out on dao classes that extends from spring's StoredProcedure class and use constructor injection.

```
@Aspect
public class Logger {

@Around("this(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) && execution(* execute(*))")
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    LOGGER.debug("time consumed = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    return result;
}
```

**Exception stacktrace:**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'myDao' defined in class path resource [spring/my-dao.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]:
Could not convert constructor argument value of type [$Proxy7] to required type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]:
Failed to convert value of type '$Proxy7 implementing org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised'
to required type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate';
nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy7 implementing org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
to required type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]:
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:702)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
```

Comment: Please show what your advice does, e.g. how and when you call `proceed`. And by the way, you do not intercept all `execute` methods, only those with exactly one parameter.

Comment: Added the code for advice. Had omitted it earlier thinking the code may not have any significance for this problem. Btw, the spring configuration also have a bean definition for JdbcTemplate which is injected into other beans.